# remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization while building project for debug

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS application when I change on swift file and try to build the application it is taking almost five minutes and building all sources files, Which leads to higher build time for every small code change

When ever build the app in build report I seeing the following warning

remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization[image: Build time for swift files with small text change in one s]

[image]

**Action taken care already :**

Incremental build

Optimization level to Fastest for debug builds

Updated project to new build system

Kindly Please check and suggest to me the way to optimize the build time, Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be a script that gets executed as a build step and modifies the source files before compilation.

Comment: Can you let me know in specific to check and corrct @VadimBelyaev

Comment: I don't know your build configuration, so I was just giving a hint. On one of my projects a build step that was modifying a plist in Settings.bundle was causing the same issue, so may be there's something similar going on in your project, not necessarily related to Settings.bundle though. I can't provide any specific help in this case.

Comment: Thank you @VadimBelyaev, let me know what project configuration would you like to check